# The requested package 'composer require nesbot/carbon' problem in Lumen 5.7 (Laravel)

Tags: lumen

I have this problem, when trying to `$composer require nesbot/carbon` and given below error

> $ composer require nesbot/carbon
>
> Using version ^2.11 for nesbot/carbon
>
> ./composer.json has been updated
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

> -illuminate/support v5.7.23 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.26.3 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0,
>   1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>           - illuminate/support v5.7.23 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.26.3 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0,
>   1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>           - illuminate/support v5.7.23 requires nesbot/carbon ^1.26.3 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0,
>   1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>           - Installation request for illuminate/support (locked at v5.7.23) -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.7.23].

I am using Laravel Lumen framework 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lumen (5.7) or Laravel (5.7) we dn't need to install Carbon because it's already include in this Library

you need to use Carbon in top of your controller e.g.

```
Use Carbon\Carbon;
```

In Controller method you need to use this

```
$now = Carbon::now();
```